# drawable resource file with selector <animation-list> recognized as StateListDrawble

Tags: android, animation

I wanted to add a frame by frame animation to my up so I used the formal reference and found the AnimationDrawable object.
here is the link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

I defined the animation in an XML file placed in the drawable folder, here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <animation-list android:id="@+id/exAnim" android:oneshot="true">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion1" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion2" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion3" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion4" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion5" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion6" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion7" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion8" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion9" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion10" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion11" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion12" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion13" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion14" android:duration="50"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion15" android:duration="50"/>
    </animation-list>

</selector>
```

i also defined an ImageView that will host the animation in the layout XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:onClick="startIt"
        android:id="@+id/fire"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_game"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then I defined a method that should start the animation when the ImageView is clicked:

```
 public void startIt(View v){
        // Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
        // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fire);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.explode_anim);

        // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getDrawable();
    }
```

When I try to click on the ImageView this exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
```

Thanks to all the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this problem.

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation);
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
animation.start();
```

I hope, this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the selector tag from the animation xml and move the xmlns attribute into the animation-list tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/exAnim" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion1" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion2" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion3" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion4" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion5" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion6" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion7" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion8" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion9" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion10" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion11" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion12" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion13" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion14" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/explosion15" android:duration="50"/>
</animation-list>
```

And it worked.